# Displaing custom message when error comes through CustomErrorHandler

Tags: angular, error-handling, http-status-code-404

I would like to create a custom pop up to inform user whenever any `http error` comes and display custom message. To do this I have created a custom `event handler` which looks like:

```
@Injectable()
export class CustomErrorHandler extends ErrorHandler {

  constructor(private errorHandlerService: ErrorHandlerService){
    super(false);
  }
  public handleError(error: any): void {
    super.handleError(error);
    if (error.status == 500){
      this.errorHandlerService.setStatus = error.status;
      alert('error 500');
    }
  }
}
```

Furthermore I have created a `service` which has only one propety - `status`:

```
@Injectable()
export class ErrorHandlerService {
  private status: any;


  get getStatus(){
    return this.status;
  }

  set setStatus(status : any){
    this.status = status;
  }
}
```

So this is a class which holds current `error status`. By the method `getStatus` I will identify if there is a necessity to display a message or not. Of course I have added in `app.module` to the `providers` section neccessary fields.

In `app.component.html` - my main `component` I have added

```
<error-handler></error-handler>
```

which will display error.

So the main question how to implement in the best way my `error-handler component`? Firstly I thought about `injecting` to the constructor my `errorHandlerService` but then I recognize that the `status` will never change. So please suggest me or tell how to do it properly.

For now I just injecting to the class my service:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'error-handler',
  templateUrl: './error-handler.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./error-handler.component.css']
})
export class ErrorHandlerComponent implements OnInit {
  showErrorMessage = false;

  constructor(private errorHandlerService: ErrorHandlerService) {}

  ngOnInit() {}

}

.html
<h1 *ngIf="showErrorMessage ">Error appears!</h1>
```

Comment: What is you add the component to the `app.component.html` with `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`? And track if there is a error by service `subscribe`ed to in the `app.component.ts`

Comment: I don't understand you. Please provide some example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> app.component.html

By adding the `<error-handler></error-handler>` to this file, its globally available at all times.

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="showErrorMessage">
  <h1>Error handler container</h1>
  <error-handler></error-handler>
</ng-container>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

> app.component.ts

```html
constructor(private errorHandlerService: ErrorHandlerService, private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

showErrorMessage = false;
ngOnInit() {
    this.errorHandlerService.getStatus().subscribe((err: any) => {
      if (err != "200") {
        showErrorMessage = true;
      } else {
        showErrorMessage = false;
      }
      this.cd.markForCheck();
    });
  }
```

> ErrorHandlerService

```js
@Injectable()
export class ErrorHandlerService {
  private status: Subject<any> = new Subject();

  getStatus(): Observable<any>{
    return this.status.asObservable();
  }

  setStatus(status : any){
    this.status.next(status);
  }
}
```

I have added few changes to the service.

> The `status` can now store the last value as long as the service is in used or otherwise destroyed.
>
> `getStatus()` method now returns a `Observable` which means you can `subscribe` to it and Angular will track for changes

```js
return this.http.get("url")
      .map((res) => res.json() as Class)
      .catch((err: Response) => Observable.throw(youmethod(err)));
```

Comment: Unfortunately this solution doesn't work. I implement it as you posted a method in `app.component.ts` -> `ngOnInit() {
    this.errorHandlerService.getStatus().subscribe((err: any) => {
      console.log('status:', err);
      if (err === "500") {
        this.showErrorMessage = true;
      } else {
        this.showErrorMessage = false;
      }
    });
  }` and the `err` is always `undefined` eventhough there is an `error http 500`

Comment: How do you set the status? And where do you set it? Could you post a snippet of that please?

Comment: Here: `public handleError(error: any): void {
    // You can add your own logic here.
    // It is not required to delegate to the original implementation
    super.handleError(error);
    if (error.status == 500){
      this.errorHandlerService.setStatus = error.status;
      alert('error 500');
    }
  }` in `custromErrorHandler` which extends `ErrorHandler`

Comment: You cannot set the value like this anymore, use this way instead  `this.errorHadlerService.setStatus (error.status);`

Comment: `status` is always `null` by default so you could change it to something else, if it throw `null pointer exceptions`

Comment: Ok, one more question. Is there any way to display that error on the page where the error occur? Now it is done in that way that whenever the error occur only after changing the page `error message` displays

Comment: Is you app `app.component.html` have same the one above? And does the `console.log('status:', err);` in the service executed even the HTML not showing?

Comment: `console.log()` appears in the service but without HTML. The `app.component.html` has the same tags but moreover I have there kind of menu

Comment: To be more precise. The HTML displays but only after I change the page/bookmark

Comment: I've updated the app.component.html, can you check if you can see the `h1` tag. This way we can see the problem on `<error-handler></error-handler>` or `app.component`.

Comment: The behaviour is the same. The `h1` appears only after I go out from the page where `error` occurs.

Comment: Do you have a `Http Interceptor`? A service that `extends Http`?

Comment: That fine, do you have this `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`?

Comment: Also haven't implemented that

Comment: Then I have no idea why that does that. I use this exact approach and it works like a charm. There might be a problem in somewhere else that you're missing

Comment: Ok, now its strange because I have added in `ngOnIniti()` in `app.component.ts` `timeout` like this: `setTimeout(function () {
      this.showErrorMessage = false;
    }, 5000)` and it displays with delay 5 sec. But I would like to display it immedietly. But when I delete this `timeout` the error message never display at the page in which error occurs.

Comment: I had that problem when I changed the `changeDetection`, just to test I've updated the `app.component.ts` with change detection method. See if that solves it.

Comment: Nothing happens for better..:/

Comment: I have changed the `service` slightly, could you check now.

Comment: Again noting changed. Still in the console has an error but nothing is displayed: https://pasteboard.co/GOr3irw.png

Comment: Are you using `Response {_body: "{"status":500,}"}`?

Comment: I am just getting status in service

Comment: I've added a sample error catch, is this how you catch errors?

Comment: No, in none of the api I catch errors. That's why I wanted to create a global error handler which will catch every error (500, 400, 404) and the display it to the user.

Comment: Could you add a snippet of your current error catch in the question please?

Comment: I don't have any error catch beside that what is in a question.

Comment: Thats why it didn't work, in order to catch error, you need to either do the way I done on last snippet or use `HttpInterceptor` approach to listen to all http request

Comment: But I/we actually caught the error. In a console there is a 'status 500' when the error occur so why should I implement `http interceptor`? The point is how to display it to the user in a real time

Comment: The error is caught by Google Chrome not your angular app. So you can't access what Chrome has. Here's a link to  Http Interceptor example https://scotch.io/@kashyapmukkamala/using-http-interceptor-with-angular2

Comment: After adding `http interceptor` it wokrs